# access view from within htmlhelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am working with mvc 4 and have created a custom HtmlHelper.

Is it possible from within that helper, to access the view that is calling the helper? I want to use properties that I have on the base view within my helper method.

Comment: Can you pass those properties into the HtmlHelper from a View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can :)

```
public static void MyExtension(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    var view = html.ViewDataContainer;

    // accessing view properties
    var viewModel = view.Model;
    var viewAjax = view.Ajax;
    // etc
}
```

Comment: `htmlHelper.ViewDataContainer` is an `IViewDataContainer` which only have the property `ViewData` and need to be casted.